# getting the current date format of a parsed date object

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

Is there a way to get the format of a given string to be parsed with the datetime format?

Something like:

```
 string_date= '2/1/99' 
 date_obj = parser.parse(string_date)
 format1 = date_obj.getdateformat
 format2 = anotherobj.getdateformat
```

Comment: Why do you want the format, when you are getting the datetime object directly when you provide your arbitrary datetime string